# How to get the item type of a List?

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose I have a "Type mytype", and if I do "mytype.ToString()", I get "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Example1.Employee]", how do I get the list item type, which is "Example1.Employee"? Do I have to parse this string to get this list item type? Is there a more *elegant* way, such as "mytype.**ItemType**"?

Also, why is there a "`1" appendix at the end of "System.Collections.Generic.List`1"?

And, why is there a "`2" at the end of "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
Type element = list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]
```

And the "`1" just indicates the number of generic parameters.

Comment: `number of generic parameters` the technical term is "arity" but not many people understand that

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes, the same as Prolog, amongst other languages. "Arity is the number of arguments or operands taken by a function or operation in logic, mathematics, and computer science."

Comment: Thank you guys! I forgot to ask: why is there a "&" at the end, for example, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Example1.Employee]&"?

Comment: @SillyDude - There's no `&` at the end of the `ToString()` output. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: @SillyDude If you did see an `&` it would represent a `ref` type, for example `ref string`, but you are only likely to see that if you are looking at function parameter types, you can also create them yourself `typeof(List<string>).MakeByRefType().ToString()` gets you `System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.String]&`